# Emails are not sent to addresses except verified addresses (Mailgun and Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailgun

I'm building a web app with Rails.

In the production environment, I want to use Mailgun to send account verification emails, but when I register with an address other than the ones I've authenticated and I am using for Heroku, I get the following error and can't send the emails.

```
Net::SMTPUnknownError (could not get 3xx (421: 421 Domain sandbox3fb706e74ad5432f99a8627384de2867.mailgun.org is not allowed to send: Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.
```

Here is my production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'protected-island-35085.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :port => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
     :address => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
     :user_name => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
     :password => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
     :domain => host,
     :authentication => :plain,
  }
```

I'm having trouble with this because I can't send emails to users after releasing the application.

The idea that Email cannot be sent to not-verified address if I use free-plan of Mailgun has come up to me, is that right?

How can I make it so that I can send emails to other addresses properly?

Also, if there is any missing information, please let me know and I will add it.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found an answer? I mean, if you cannot send to "unverified addresses" (all emails in a web app!), then what is the meaning of saying 12,000 free emails per month!? If that's true, I'll move to another company that has better marketing practices